# How to extract titles as links from a list of Org files in a directory

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a list of org files under a directory:

```
> org-file1.org
> org-file2.org
> org-file3.org
> ...
> org-fileN.org
```

I want to extract their titles (using `#+title` tag) as links as follows:

```
 [[file:org-file1.org][title for org file 1]]
 [[file:org-file2.org][title for org file 2]]
 [[file:org-file3.org][title for org file 3]]
 ...
 [[file:org-fileN.org][title for org file N]]
```

How can I extract these as a list using Emacs Lisp?

Comment: Maybe you will get an answer here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has posted it on both SO and SE Emacs.

Comment: I don't really understand why [the question/answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71404/how-to-extract-titles-as-links-from-a-list-of-org-files-in-a-directory) on SE Emacs got hidden, it was a complete answer to the solution, and also I guess questions about org-mode probably more belong to SE Emacs. @NickD I think in that answer on SE, the regex did not have to be anchored because it was using `looking-at-p` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: The OP chose to delete that question and keep this one.

Comment: @dalanicolai: I pastebinned your answer to the other question [here](https://pastebin.com/fSpWCgru), if you would like to add it to this question.

Comment: @NickD Ah thanks! As I think it will be nice, I will indeed add it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `org-element-api` for this, but in this case it is probably easier/faster to simply search by regexp using looking-at-p. To get all files in a directory, there is `directory-files(-recursively)`. Then finally you could achieve it using the following function:

```lisp
(defun extract-org-directory-titles-as-list (&optional dir)
  (interactive "D")
  (print
   (delete nil
           (let ((case-fold-search t))
             (mapcar (lambda (f)
                       (when (string-match "org$" f)
                         (with-temp-buffer
                           (insert-file-contents-literally
                            (concat (file-name-as-directory dir) f))
                           (while (and (not (looking-at-p "#\\+TITLE:"))
                                       (not (eobp)))
                             (forward-line))
                           (when (not (eobp))
                             (cons f (substring (thing-at-point 'line) 9 -1))))))
                     (directory-files dir))))))

(defun insert-directory-org-file-titles (&optional dir)
  (interactive "D")
  (let ((files-titles (extract-org-directory-titles-as-list dir)))
    (dolist (ft files-titles)
      (insert (concat "[[file:" (car ft)"][" (cdr ft) "]]\n")))))
```

If you prefer to just have it as a (a)list, like you asked, then just use `extract-org-directory-titles-as-list`.

Comment: I am very new to elisp.  so can I use sth like (insert-directory-org-file-titles "~/org" ) to get the list?

Comment: I have split the function in two functions for clarity (and slightly improved/corrected it). You can use it like you suggested, or use it interactively via `M-x` (of course you have to evaluate/load the code first). B.t.w. when you hide some answer, it would be nice to let the person know (why).

Comment: It is working as expected, almost.  Any point on why it does not encode the chinese title correctly (right now it is dispalyed as raw data. eg. \244)\206 etc.  the file name is ok though)?   I did not mean to hide the answer. The OP told me that I am not supposed to ask twice. So I delete post on Emacs

Comment: for some reason, I can not get `directory-files-recursively` working?

Comment: `(directory-files-recursively "~/org" "\.org$" )` runs ok.  `(directory-files-recursively "~/org" "\.org$" )` will add a redundant path and fails (e.g. /home/x/org/home/x/org).

Comment: change this `(concat (file-name-as-directory dir) f))` to `f`,  recursive looping working now.  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with encodings. If you would like to see what the code does (for example when you replace `directory-files`), then you could [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Edebug.html) it. It is simple and very powerful.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance.   I will leave it as is now since the html output displays ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that can be used on a single file to get the title. It's part of an org mode file that can be used for testing. Save it as an Org mode file, visit it in Emacs and type `C-c C-c` on the code block. Change the title and evaluate the code block again.

```el
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+TITLE: This is a very nice title, don't you think?
#+AUTHOR: A.U. Thor

* foo
bar


* Code

#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search t))
      (search-forward-regexp "^#\\+TITLE:")
      (org-element-property :value (org-element-context (org-element-at-point)))))
#+end_src


#+RESULTS:
:results:
This is a very nice title, don't you think?
:end:
```

The code block goes to the beginning of the buffer, searches forward for the string `#+TITLE:` at the beginning of a line (the search is case-insensitive) and then uses some functions from the `org-element` library to parse the buffer at point, get the context and get the `:value` property out of it.

In order to make it into a complete solution, you have to:

- make it more robust: check that this is a title keyword not just some random junk that happened to satisfy the match, although that's unlikely; but better safe than sorry.
- wrap it in a loop that does a `find-file` on every file  in the directory and gets the title for each file and returns a list of tuples: `(filename title)` that you can easily use to create your links.